# How to maintain environment variables in Path when adding new Path folder

Tags: c#, .net, path, windows-10, environment-variables

I am trying to add a folder to my "Path" environment variable by doing the following:

```
string path = Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable("Path", EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
path = path + @";C:\my\new\path";
Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable("Path", path, EnvironmentVariableTarget.Machine);
```

This adds my new folder to the Path variable successfully, however any existing Path folders that had been represented by an environment variable are now expanded out.

For example, I have an environment variable JAVA_HOME that points to C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17, and in the Path variable I originally had an entry that read %JAVA_HOME%\bin.  However, after doing the above update, now that Path entry reads C:\Program Files\Java\jdk-17\bin.

When I examine the string returned by Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable(), I see that it returns the paths already expanded out rather than the %JAVA_HOME% placeholder.  How do I update the Path variable without saving the existing paths in their expanded forms and instead maintain their variable names?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems that `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` always expands environment variables which are embedded in other environment variables, and there's no option to change this behaviour.

You could instead try reading the environment variable from the registry, e.g.

```
using System;
using Microsoft.Win32;

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var keyName = @"SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment";
        var key = Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(keyName);
        var pathFromRegistry = key.GetValue("Path", "not found", RegistryValueOptions.DoNotExpandEnvironmentNames);
        Console.WriteLine(pathFromRegistry);
    }
}
```

I wrote this example in a .net core 3.1 console application, which needed the `Microsoft.Win32.Registry` nuget package before the `Microsoft.Win32` namespace could be used.

There's a [GitHub issue](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/1442) with discussion about why `Environment.GetEnvironmentVariable` doesn't provide this same functionality.

Comment: Thank you for this.  I read through that GitHub thread and it looks like this issue with the API is even more damaging than I expected.  It looks like SetEnvironmentVariable also changes the registry type of "PATH" that causes it to interpret %var% as literal text rather than expandable, so even doing a "Get" that maintains the %var% notation will break it when saving with "Set".  I was looking to see if there was a command line solution, but it looks like "setx" has the same issue of changing the registry type, AND truncates the value to 1024 characters.

Comment: Yeah, it's a bit ugly. Normally I'd stay well away from editing the registry directly, but in this case it looks like the least worst option.

Comment: it seems this registry gets the `system env variables`, what about update the `user env variables`? I'd like to update the `PATH` env variable of the _current user_.